# JSF send XML String in inputtextarea

Tags: xml, jsf

I am bit new to **JSF**. Facing an issue when trying to put an **XML** string in a `inputtextarea`.
I have an XHTML file within which there is a code:

```
<h:inputTextarea title="Enter Text" rows="5" cols="120"
                                    value="#{managedBean1..message}"
```

and have a normal setter and getter in the backing bean class.

In input text area when i am trying to set an XML string, in the setter of backing bean it is coming as normal string with removal of the angle brackets(< and >).

Please suggest what changes are required so the XML string goes as it is in the backing bean

Comment: You have two `.(dots)` after `managedBean1..message` I don't think this is the problem i tried it and it worked fine can you mention your all code and tools you used (:

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Your problem is not at all reproducible when you would try it on a blank project. Your problem is caused elsewhere in your existing project. Most likely there's some sort of a "XSS filter" in your webapp which does the XSS-sanitizing job the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update, based on your input i was able to dig the application code and was able to find the root cause of the problem.
There is a filter implemented for the JSF page that is restricting usage of angle brackets and filtering them out.

Problem is solved now.